# Google AppEngine, multiple custom domains and static files

Tags: google-app-engine

I am working on an application that runs on Google AppEngine (Java), using the custom domain X.com.  Each user of the application are assigned a custom URL, in the form userName.Y.com.  Currently, both X.com and *.Y.com are assigned to the AppEngine application, and I have a servlet filter that determines the data to return when userName.Y.com is accessed.

The problem, though, is when a static file is used. If I have a static file X.com/index.html, I can access the same file when I visit userName.Y.com/index.html, and my filter isn't called at all. I suspect that's because index.html is a static file and it is served outside of the JVM and the filter isn't invoked.

Here are the things I have considered:

1. I can make everything in X.com dynamic (not static files) -- then the filter will kick in and everything will work as expected. However, this is not ideal for performance.
2. I can deploy 2 different application, one for files in X.com and one for fetching data for Y.com -- this is very heavy for maintenance as I have to make sure everything is in-sync, and I need to expose an API for the filter in Y.com to access the data stored in X.com.
3. Similarly, I can copy my static files to a CDN, and make everything dynamic -- then do a 304 to serve static files off the CDN.  This has performance implications as well.

It seems like none of the solutions I thought of is ideal (in terms of performance and maintenance) -- is there a better way?  Ideally, I need a solution that doesn't involve multiple deployments (either multiple apps or versions) but doesn't have a heavy performance penalty.

Comment: Why not use cloudstorage to serve your files. Google will do the serving. But (from the docs): You can use a CNAME redirect only with HTTP, not with HTTPS.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, I need HTTPS -- also, it's similar to option 2 where I'd have to manage 2 deployments -- but it does sound better than option 2 though!

Comment: It is similar to a CDN. I use it for all kinds of files except for html files, and I use the CDN (Google storage) domain name. I use different cloudstorage folders for the files of my domains.

Comment: Look in the html source of this test site, where cloudstorage is used for js, css, pdf and images: https://eurocodicil-dot-jinjacms2.appspot.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1 is by far the easiest and you have full control over what will be served. In terms of performance, I would not worry either. if you send the right cache-control headers with the server response, then the GAE Frontend will be serving your file without hitting your instances.

Comment: Yes, I guess Solution 1 is probably what I'd go for. Hopefully the page will be cached in the GAE front end cache so the performance impact would be low.